# Android direction in Google Maps with latitude and longitude

Tags: android, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, directions

I want send my origin point and destination point to Google for direction. 
When I use name for origin and destination it's true and returns true JSON information, but when I send latitude and longitude for origin and destination it doesn't work.

It's ok whit this URL:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=tehran&destination=shiraz&key=AIzaSyBvR07aFM-1ddGVgt392lRnUge3weT6nUY

But it doesn't work with this:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=32,52&destination=34,54&key=AIzaSyBvR07aFM-1ddGVgt392lRnUge3weT6nUY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is the coordinates you're using - they look like they're not accessible via roads.  Make sure that you're not casting the latitude or longitude to ints, you need the decimal-point precision.

Converting Tehran and Shiraz to latlngs, I get the following URL which works correctly:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=35.6887931,51.3891646&destination=29.5916593,52.583701&key=<api key here>`

Comment: when I use from your url it work correctly but when I change one digit of the point it doesnt work----I change 29.5916593 to 23.5916593--test this in browser

Comment: That makes sense, changing the 29 => 23 moves the destination to a location in the UAE where there are no roads. https://www.google.com/maps/dir/'35.6887931,51.3891646'/23.5916593,52.583701/@24.8469356,51.9801806,475369m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m6!4m5!1m3!2m2!1d51.3891646!2d35.6887931!1m0